# SQL COUNT between dates in two different column

Tags: sql, count, null, between

Let's say, we have this table:

```
STUDENT |  START  | END
1       |1998-1-1 |2001-1-1
2       |1999-1-1 |2001-1-1
3       |2000-1-1 |2004-1-1
4       |2000-1-1 | NULL
```

I'm trying to do is:

Count number of students between start and end dates!

Comment: What do you mean "between" dates? Do you mean a given date is between start and end, or a given date range "overlaps" the start and end? Or something else?

Comment: I wanted sql that count student who started between dates and count student who ended study between dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to use a basic `COUNT` aggregate:

```
SELECT COUNT(Student)
FROM YourTable
WHERE Start >= @Start 
    AND End <= @End
```

I've used >= and <= respectively around the start and end date fields.  Feel free to change to > or < as needed.  It was unclear from your question whether you wanted between a specific field or if you were checking for a range between those two fields.

Answer (score 1):

Use the between Operator and COUNT aggregate function

```
SELECT COUNT(student) column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name
BETWEEN value1 AND value2
```

Between can be used with text so insert the dates where the values are,

Read more here if you still don't understand

EDIT : That should work, sorry about the error

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: What the OP wants is to `Count number of students between start and end dates`. Your answer just return a set of rows.