# Get the number of added values in Database in the last month by weeks?PHP Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to show the number of rows added in database per week in last 1 month: 
i already tried this query but it shows the number by weeks for all the time i mean not just the last 1 month. so that code shows the number within the last 1 week

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT count(*) 
                  FROM reclamations
                  WHERE work = 'done'
                  AND reclamation_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 week")
```

But actually i want to get the number by week yeah but just for the last 1month

Comment: ^... assuming you stamp the rows with the date/time they are added

Comment: @PatrickQ you could use the binlog

Comment: can u please help me,

Comment: Hi @YaSSin - if you can put in more details about the things that you have tried so far you'll probably have better luck.

Comment: @doublesharp ahhhh, sneaky. Although getting the count by week that way would probably be unpleasant.

Comment: @PatrickQ yeah there is a column for date in the database

Comment: @PatrickQ I never said it would be pleasant :P

Comment: @doublesharp i'm just asking about the possibility i'll try to do something, and post it, thank u

Comment: It will take less time to Google than it does to post to SO :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL COUNT between dates in two different column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384273/sql-count-between-dates-in-two-different-column)

Comment: i already google it but i can't find anything helpful

Comment: This really isn't a place to ask "Is XYZ possible".  This is more of a place for "I tried XYZ and it didn't work. Here's what I tried, here's the desired result, here's the actual result (and/or any errors). What do I do to fix it?"

Comment: @PatrickQ yeah i know but i need somehelp i didn't find anything about my problem so i thought if i put a question here i can have some documentation and try to do my best

Comment: "i already google it but i can't find anything helpful"  How do you know that what you found wasn't helpful? Did you try anything? If you did, you should include what you tried in your question, along with the desired and actual results.

Comment: yeah i tried , ok i'll edit the question so it can be more specific and clear

Comment: @PatrickQ i don't know if u get what i want to say but i hope u can and give me something helpful thx by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the count per week for the last month, you will need to change your interval to `MONTH` and add a [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html) to your existing query. You can use the [`WEEK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) MySQL function to get the week of the year value from your date. Note that if there is any missing data in your time series - a week with no data - it will be missing from the results.

```
SELECT WEEK(reclamation_date) week_of_year, count(*) entry_count, 
FROM reclamations
WHERE work = 'done'
  AND reclamation_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY WEEK(reclamation_date)
```