# In SQL, how can you calculate maximum concurrent number of users

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table.

this table has usage period of user.

example is follow

```
|user_id|start_at  |end_at    |
|1      |2014/11/02|2014/11/05|
|2      |2014/11/03|2014/11/07|
|3      |2014/11/08|2014/11/09|
```

I would like to get maximum concurrent number of users

above case,

Between 2014/11/03 ~ 2014/05, 2 user used.

I would like to get this "2".

Is there an easy way to set this up? What do you recommend?

Comment: Where are "Users" ? What You specified is UserId..

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL COUNT between dates in two different column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384273/sql-count-between-dates-in-two-different-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum is going to occur at one of the `start_at` times.  So, you can do this with a self-join:

```
select u.start_at, count(*) as numconcurrent
from usage u join
     usage u2
     on u.start_at between u2.start_at and u2.end_at
group by u.start_at
```

If you want the maximum number, then add:

```
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Thank you!
I could get max count.

Comment: Thank you for rescuing me from my brain. I was convinced I'd need a recursive CTE or something coupled with weird windowing functions.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you may have mis-stated the question. Do you really mean "max" ?   or just the number of users between two dates ? If that is so, then

```
Select count(*) from table 
where start_at < @end
   and end_at > @start
```

Comment: then you need to rephrase your question, because it is not clear what you mean by "max"

Comment: Sorry and hank you for pointing this out.
I rephrase my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(case when start_at >= @startdate and end_at <= @enddate 
          then 1 
          else 0 
    end) as total
```

this would follow a qualifying set declare statement or embedded in a stored procedure. Your choice.

This will increment by 1 every time it sees a row that meets those credentials and sum the total.